# why django development server act like single thread while the docs "The server is multithreaded by default."-- version 2.1

Tags: django

I am a beginner of Django web framework, and I'm using Django 2.1.2. Now I encountered one question, does Django run in single thread or multithreads ？I checked the docs and it says 'the server is multithreaded by default.' while i have tested in my local env, it act just like single-thread.

my view functions is:

```
class Hello(APIView):
"""
   for testing django single-threading
"""
    def get(self, request):
        print("enter in the view")
        time.sleep(10)
        print("finished...")
        return HttpResponse("finished!")
```

I run Django application in terminal by:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

I requested the url twice at nearly the same time, and the reponse is:

```
enter in the view
finished...
[13/Jan/2019 10:43:50] "GET /account/hello HTTP/1.1" 200 9
enter in the view
finished...
[13/Jan/2019 10:44:00] "GET /account/hello HTTP/1.1" 200 9
```

It handled requests just like in single-thread way, did I do something wrong or I understand in wrong, thanks for help.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/  python manage.py runserver

Comment: How are you sending these requests to django?

Comment: @knbk using browser

Comment: `runserver` is in fact multi-threaded by default, and I have no issues triggering simultaneous requests. I can't tell if your browser is doing something funky or if something's wrong with your setup,

Comment: @knbk Thanks for your help, I found that this is because my chrome browser send requests to same url by "single thread", not the django development server handle requests by  single thread. I am using chrome  71.0.3578.98.